# Cloudfoundry Deploy Micro Bosh Fails

Tags: ruby, vmware, cloud-foundry

I am trying to follow this guide here:  http://kendrickcoleman.com/index.php/Tech-Blog/from-zero-to-cloud-foundry-on-vsphere-part-1-how-to-install-microbosh.html

I am up to step 13.

I get a error in the log:

```
I, [2014-10-08T15:57:11.460375 #30531] [attach_disk(vm-3bfd53b7-1bac-44e1-b6a9-87454f9d0f88, disk-e1e99cad-1c98-4096-a78c-4b81ee1509ee)]  INFO -- : Updating agent env to: {"vm"=>{"name"=>"vm-3bfd53b7-1bac-44e1-b6a9-87454f9d0f88", "id"=>"vm-8857"},
 "agent_id"=>"bm-913097b0-3865-4f87-b5b1-9608e66b34c9",
 "networks"=>
  {"bosh"=>
    {"cloud_properties"=>{"name"=>"Network Private"},
     "netmask"=>"mynetmask",
     "gateway"=>"mygateway",
     "ip"=>"myip",
     "dns"=>["mydns"],
     "type"=>nil,
     "default"=>["dns", "gateway"],
     "mac"=>"00:50:56:93:17:23"}},
 "disks"=>
  {"system"=>"0",
   "ephemeral"=>"1",
   "persistent"=>{"disk-e1e99cad-1c98-4096-a78c-4b81ee1509ee"=>"2"}},
 "ntp"=>["ntp.example.com.au"],
 "blobstore"=>
  {"provider"=>"local",
   "options"=>{"blobstore_path"=>"/var/vcap/micro_bosh/data/cache"}},
 "mbus"=>"https://vcap:b00tstrap@0.0.0.0:6868",
 "env"=>{"bosh"=>{"password"=>nil}}}

I, [2014-10-08T15:57:18.350121 #30531] [attach_disk(vm-3bfd53b7-1bac-44e1-b6a9-87454f9d0f88, disk-e1e99cad-1c98-4096-a78c-4b81ee1509ee)]  INFO -- : Attaching disk
I, [2014-10-08T15:57:20.381994 #30531] [attach_disk(vm-3bfd53b7-1bac-44e1-b6a9-87454f9d0f88, disk-e1e99cad-1c98-4096-a78c-4b81ee1509ee)]  INFO -- : Finished attaching disk
```

This is what my console says:

```
  Started deploy micro bosh > Mount disk. Done (00:00:07)
     Done deploy micro bosh > Updating persistent disk (00:00:17)
  Started deploy micro bosh > Stopping agent services. Done (00:00:01)
  Started deploy micro bosh > Applying micro BOSH spec/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/bosh_cli_plugin_micro-1.2732.0/lib/bosh/deployer/instance_manager/vsphere.rb:32:in `[]': no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/bosh_cli_plugin_micro-1.2732.0/lib/bosh/deployer/instance_manager/vsphere.rb:32:in `update_spec'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/bosh_cli_plugin_micro-1.2732.0/lib/bosh/deployer/instance_manager.rb:380:in `block in apply'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/bosh_cli_plugin_micro-1.2732.0/lib/bosh/deployer/instance_manager.rb:85:in `step'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/bosh_cli_plugin_micro-1.2732.0/lib/bosh/deployer/instance_manager.rb:378:in `apply'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/bosh_cli_plugin_micro-1.2732.0/lib/bosh/deployer/instance_manager.rb:146:in `create'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/bosh_cli_plugin_micro-1.2732.0/lib/bosh/deployer/instance_manager.rb:98:in `block in create_deployment'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/bosh_cli_plugin_micro-1.2732.0/lib/bosh/deployer/instance_manager.rb:92:in `with_lifecycle'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/bosh_cli_plugin_micro-1.2732.0/lib/bosh/deployer/instance_manager.rb:98:in `create_deployment'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/bosh_cli_plugin_micro-1.2732.0/lib/bosh/cli/commands/micro.rb:179:in `perform'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/bosh_cli-1.2732.0/lib/cli/command_handler.rb:57:in `run'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/bosh_cli-1.2732.0/lib/cli/runner.rb:56:in `run'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/bosh_cli-1.2732.0/lib/cli/runner.rb:16:in `run'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/bosh_cli-1.2732.0/bin/bosh:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/bin/bosh:23:in `load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/bin/bosh:23:in `<main>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
root@vmt-cf-01:/bosh/deployments#
```

I am not getting enough info to help my googleing.  Any ideas?

thanks

Comment: The line of code where the failure is occurring is here: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/bosh/blob/master/bosh_cli_plugin_micro/lib/bosh/deployer/instance_manager/vsphere.rb#L32.  The error message implies that something is an array but the code is trying to access elements of it as though it were a hash with String keys.  My guess is your Micro BOSH deployment manifest (similar to http://kendrickcoleman.com/phocadownload/userupload/micro_bosh_nodescriptors.yml) is wrong...

Comment: ... In particular I'd guess that your `apply_spec.properties.vcenter` looks like an array instead of a hash.  It's confusing because under `cloud.properties.vcenters` it looks the same, but there it should be an array.  The difference is whether the appropriate line says `- host: some_address` or `host: some_address` (without the `-` to indicate array).

Comment: Amit, champion.  Looks to be right, a `-` too many.  At home now, but will test tomorrow, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Confirmed, this from Amit fixed my issue.

... In particular I'd guess that your apply_spec.properties.vcenter looks like an array instead of a hash. It's confusing because under cloud.properties.vcenters it looks the same, but there it should be an array. The difference is whether the appropriate line says - host: some_address or host: some_address (without the - to indicate array).

Comment: You should accept this answer, might be useful for the next person who comes along.